# Retrieve local components using Core Service

Tags: core-service

I have a console app that is using the Core Service to try and retrieve localized and local components for a given publication Id. I've had a look at the documentation on SDL Live Content and have managed to get as far as the following:

```
using (var client = new BlueprintReports.CoreService.CoreServiceClient("basicHttp"))
{
    var filterdata = new RepositoryItemsFilterData();
    filterdata.Recursive = true;
    filterdata.ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Component };

    XElement resultxml = client.GetListXml(_publicationId, filterdata);
    if (resultxml != null)
    {
        foreach (var component in resultxml.Elements())
        {
            var compData = (ComponentData)client.Read(component.Attribute("ID").Value, 
                                                      new ReadOptions());
            if (compData.BluePrintInfo.IsLocalized == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(component.Attribute("ID").Value);
            }
        }
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

What the above code is doing is writing out the tcm Id of each localized component. However what I also need to do is check against local components i.e. components that have been created at the specific publication (_publicationId in the above example).

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit: just re-read your question:

```
if (compData.BluePrintInfo.IsShared == false)
{
     Console.WriteLine(component.Attribute("ID").Value);
}
```

That should print for Components local to the current context publication and those that have been localized.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I now just have a check for IsShared == false as it will always fall back to local/localized items.